# navigator.cookieEnabled is not working in IE 9 ++

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

```
$window.navigator.cookieEnabled
```

or

```
navigator.cookieEnabled
```

Above code  always gives true .

But Rest of the bowers are quite intelligent enough to get the cookie value.

How to solve this **issue in IE** .

Suggest please.

Comment: $window in Angularjs and Window in pure javascript

Comment: Please consider adding a comment when voting down so that the question can be improved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found Solution:

1 - Change the privacy setting to Internet ,this will make all cookies blocked.
2 -  Use loopback or 127.0.0.1 rather localhost 
2 -  Use ip rather localhost

Self Achived